# Sitecore nested Bucketing

Tags: buckets, dictionary

We are having list of dictionary items where the Dictionary folder is a bucket, and the Dictionary entry is a bucketable item. Often, we are having Dictionary folder inside another Dictionary folder, hence when we are syncing the parent folder the dictionary item inside the nested folders are bucketed under the first level outer folder instead of its own immediate parent dictionary folder.

Is there any fix or work around available please?Below screenshots show the before and after bucketing tree structure.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have Dictionary under `System` or do you have it in your site content? And are you using SXA OOTB dictionary or do you have any folder for `Dictionary`?

Comment: Can you please clarify the question with more detail and maybe some screen shots around what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @RichardSeal  Have added screenshot for more clarity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SumitBhatia Bhatia Have added screenshot for more clarity. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try to select checkbox under Item buckets section on Item template that says "Lock child relationship" prior enabling bucket and syncing? This should keep items structured correctly.

Comment: @SumitBhatia It is SXA, so the dictionary are OOTB and is site specific.

Answer (score 0):

To keep items structured in buckets. Before making item bucketable and syncing, select checkbox under Item template `Item Buckets` section called `Lock child relationship`
[image]

Once this is done and synced, your bucket should be structured like:
[image]

Comment: Hi Kamil thanks for the suggestion, we tried it but it is not working... however will check again if I had missed anything.